# Variadic template packed argument to std::vector

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm new to templates and I don't really undestand why this doesn't work. I expected the vector to be constructed with those values.

***main.cpp***

```cpp
template <typename ...T>
void int_printf(T ...args)
{
    std::vector<T> vec = {args...};

    for(auto& v:vec)
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int_printf(1,2,3,4);

    return 0;
}
```

***Expected result***

```
1
2
3
4
```

***Error by msvc compiler*** (translated)

```cpp
src/main.cpp(35): error C3520: 'T': the parameter pack must be expanded in this context
src/main.cpp(37): error C3536: '<begin>$L0': can't be used before initialization
src/main.cpp(37): error C3536: '<end>$L0': can't be used before initialization
src/main.cpp(37): error C2100: invalid redirection
```

Comment: What about `int_printf(3, nullptr, -9e134, "hello", main);`, what is the type of `vec`?

Comment: that hurts , I know that the problem should be in the std::vector<T> but I don't know how to make it work just for ints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another, slightly more wordy, way to do this is to add an initial template parameter specifying the type of `vec`, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
void int_printf(Args ... args)
{
    std::vector<T> vec = {args...};

    for (auto& v : vec)
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int_printf<int>(1,2,3,4);
    return 0;
}
```

This might give clearer error messages if you pass a list of incompatible types to `int_printf`.

Answer (score 5):

The issue in your code, is that `T` is not a template parameter in this context, it is a template parameter pack, which would expand to `T=[int,int,int,int]` in your example. `std::vector` expects a type to be passed as a template parameter, not a template parameter pack. You can solve this issue by using `std::common_type`:

```
#include<type_traits>

template <typename ...T>
void int_printf(T ...args)
{
    //use std::common_type to deduce common type from template
    //   parameter pack
    std::vector<typename std::common_type<T...>::type> vec = {args...};

    for(auto& v:vec)
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You should note, this will only work if the arguments passed to `int_printf` have a common type.

Comment: @MooingDuck looks interesting but how I implement it?

Answer (score 2):

When you do `std::vector<T>`, the `T` is not a single type but is instead is a pack of types.  You can't use that for the vector because it wants a single type for the element.

There is a couple ways to handle this.  First would be to just hard code the type of the vector.  This makes the code less generic, but would work for you since your function is called `int_printf` and not `anything_print`

Another option is to use [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) to get the common type of the elements like

```
template <typename ...T>
void int_printf(T ...args)
{
    std::vector<std::common_type_t<T...>> vec = {args...};

    for(auto& v:vec)
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You could also use a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) and skip the vector entirely like

```
template <typename ...T>
void int_printf(T ...args)
{
    ((std::cout << args << std::endl), ...);
//  ^^                                    ^
//  |          do this part         ^  ^  |
//  |              for each parameter  |  |
//  start fold expression          end fold
}
```

If you want just an unlimited number of `int`'s you could also use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to constrain the pack type to be integers like

```
template <typename ...T, std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T, int>...>, bool> = true>
void int_printf(T ...args)
{
    ((std::cout << args << std::endl), ...);
}
```

and now you can't call this function with anything other than `int`'s but it can have as many as you want.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I don't undestand why in the folded version you put a coma `endl), ..."` . Could you explain that to me please?

Comment: @ElGusanito What I am doing is abusing the comma operator.  What I'm saying is do `(std::cout << args << std::endl)` for each parameter of the argument pack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `std::variant` in conjunction with `std::vector`. Here is an example:

```
template<typename... Args>
class VariantTest
{
private:
    using ArgTypes = std::variant<Args...>;
    std::vector<ArgTypes> elems;
public:
    VariantTest()
    {
        elems.reserve(10); //just a number
    }

    template<typename... ArgsL>
    void AddTypes(ArgsL&&... args)
    {
        (elems.emplace_back(std::forward<ArgsL>(args)), ...);
    }
    size_t GetElemsCount()
    {
        return elems.size();
    }
};

int main()
{

    VariantTest<A, B> vt;
    vt.AddTypes(B(), A()); //Note the order does not matter.
    std::cout << "Number of elements: " << vt.GetElemsCount() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

You will need C++17.